# Finding Rectangle which contains a Point

Tags: java, java-2d

In Java SE 7, I'm trying to solve a problem where I have a series of Rectangles. Through some user interaction, I get a Point. What I need to do is find the (first) Rectangle which contains the Point (if any).

Currently, I'm doing this via the very naieve solution of just storing the Rectangles in an ArrayList, and searching for the containing Rectangle by iterating over the list and using `contains()`. The problem is that, because this needs to be interactive for the user, this technique starts to be too slow for even a relatively small number of Rectangles (say, 200).

My current code looks something like this:

```
// Given rects is an ArrayList<Rectangle>, and p is a Point:

for(Rectangle r : rects)
{
    if(r.contains(p))
    {
        return r;
    }
}

return null;
```

Is there a more clever way to solve this problem (namely, in O(log n) instead of O(n), and/or with fewer calls to `contains()` by eliminating obviously bad candidates early)?

Comment: `The problem is that, because this needs to be interactive for the user, this technique starts to be too slow for even a relatively small number of Rectangles (say, 200).` there must be something else wrong with the code. Iterating over 200 Rectangles will not take any time.

Comment: You're right. A simple profile shows that this isn't even close to the majority of the time I'm spending to handle a mouse click (it turns out it takes about 8ms on my fairly average laptop). I am still curious about this problem in a more general sense, though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, there is. Build 2 [interval trees](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interval_tree) which will tell you if there is a rectangle between x1 to x2 and between y1 and y2. Then, when you have the co-ordinates of the point, perform O(log n) searches in both the trees.

That'll tell you if there are possibly rectangles around the point of interest. You still need to check if there is a common rectangle given by the two trees.

Comment: The Wikipedia article mentions several ways to extend a standard interval tree to two dimensions. This should work great for my problem. The question is, though, is there an existing implementation of this in Java?

Comment: There is a Java implementation in the article itself. Also read the section after the Java implementation to get an idea about building 2-dimensional trees using the same code. Personally, I find that to be too complex and try to keep things simple.

Comment: Here is a complete implementation with insert, delete and search: http://algs4.cs.princeton.edu/93intersection/IntervalST.java.html